# Почему после конвертации файла через PDFCreater в PDF содержимое нечитабельно

Tags: .net, powershell, pdf, com

Мне требуется конвертировать некоторое количество файлов с разным разрешением от .txt до .excel в DPFA2B формат, но после конвертации содержимое файлов становится нечитаемым если использовать код ниже, хотя при конвертации этих же файлов через интерфейс PDFCreater все отображается корректно. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

**Задаю путь до файла которые надо сконвертировать**
`$FilePath = "D:\Users\Veks\Desktop\Михеенко Анатолий, RPA developer.docx"`

**Создаю COM объект для PDFCreator**
`$PDFCreator = New-Object -ComObject PDFCreator.JobQueue`

**Инициализирую COM объект PDFCreator**
`$PDFCreator.Initialize()`

**Отправляю файл на печать**
`Get-Content -Path $FilePath | Out-Printer -Name "PDFCreator"`

**Жду появления этого файла в очереди на печать**
`while ($PDFCreator.count -lt 1){start-sleep 2}`

**Получаю файл из очереди на печать**
`$PJ = $PDFCreator.NextJob`

**Задаю формат текста для файла**
`$PJ.SetProfileSetting("TextSettings.Format", "3")`

**Задаю формат файла**
`$PJ.SetProfileSetting("OutputFormat","PdfA2B")`

**Конвертирую файл**
`$PJ.ConvertTo("D:\Users\Veks\Desktop\TEST.pdf")`

**Завершаю COM объект**
`$PDFCreator.ReleaseCom()`

Как файл выглядит изначально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После конвертации
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас опечатка в метке. Не powersheel, а powershell.

Comment: Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что `Get-Content` читает вордовский файл как текстовый, а не как офисный. И зачем использовать стороннюю утилиту, если можно это сделать "родным" вордом? [Решение на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16537996/15035314)

Comment: Проблема в том, что на вход может прийти не только вордовский файл

Comment: [Здесь](https://techexpert.tips/powershell/powershell-printing-file/) показано, как распечатать файлы различных типов